# Cannot find dynamic library when running a Python script from Bazel

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, bazel

I am trying to setup CUDA enabled Python & TensorFlow environment on OSx 10.11.6

Everything went quite smoothly. First I installed following:

- CUDA - 7.5
- cuDNN - 5.1

I ensured that the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and CUDA_HOME are set properly by adding following into my ~/.bash_profile file:

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda 
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CUDA_HOME/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CUDA_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export PATH="$CUDA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Then I used Brew to install following:

- python - 2.7.12_2
- bazel - 0.3.2
- protobuf - 3.1.0

Then I used Pip to install CPU only TensorFlow from:
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl

I checked out the Magenta project from: https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta
and run all the test using:

```
bazel test //magenta/...
```

And all of them have passed.

So far so good. So I decided to give the GPU enabled version of TensorFlow a shot and installed it from:
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/gpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl

Now all the tests fail with the following error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.7.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found
```

So obviously the script run from Bazel has trouble locating the libcudart.7.5.dylib library.

I did try running GPU computations from Python without Bazel and everything seems to be fine.

I also did create a test script and run it using Bazel and it seems that the directory containing libcudart.7.5.dylib library is reachable, however the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set.

I searched the documentation and found --action_env and --test_env flags, but none of them actually seems to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH for the execution.

These are the options from loaded from .bazelrc files.

```
Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=80
Inherited 'build' options: --define=allow_oversize_protos=true --copt -funsigned-char -c opt --spawn_strategy=standalone
'run' options: --spawn_strategy=standalone
```

What is the correct way to let Bazel know about the runtime dependencies?

**UPDATE**

The trouble seems to be caused by the fact that "env" command is part of the execution chain and it does seem to clear both LD_LIBRARY_PATH and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environmental variables. Is there a workaround different than disabling the SIP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [SIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection) affects the behavior of how the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH gets propagated to the child processes. I found a [similar problem](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/231) and another [similar problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/waugt62RQMU).

I didn't want to turn the SIP off, so I just created symlinks for the CUDA library into a standard location.

```
ln -s /usr/local/cuda/lib/* /usr/local/lib
```

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it does work and it does not require the SIP to be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/
```

before launching bazel. Double check in the directory above if there is such a file.

```
ls /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.7.5.dylib
```

Note that in Macosx the name is different:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib/
```

See this answer for more information on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/282450/where-do-i-set-dyld-library-path-on-mac-os-x-and-is-it-a-good-idea)

Comment: Does it have to be lib64 directory? My CUDA comes with a lib directory only. I tried to rename it and export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but no luck. 

Again if I run python somefile.py everything is fine, but if I do bazel //directory:target_with_the_same_file it's broken. So I think I am missing some Bazel options and my environment setup is fine.

Comment: no it does not matter if is lib64 or lib, but it has to match the path. Are you on macosx ? the LD_LIBRARY_PATH is different on mac. is DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I actually set both the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH just to be sure. From the tests I run so far it seems that Python is able to pick either one of them, whereas the Bazel just clears them both out during execution.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer here.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/41073045/1831325

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed SIP, and the solution is to pass `--action_env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CUDA_HOME/lib` to the `bazel` command, e.g.:

`bazel build -c opt --config=cuda --action_env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CUDA_HOME/lib //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Building your own TensorFlow is certainly an option. However I remember having some issues with compatibility of all the dependencies so I ended up using the pre-build one.