# Python module cannot load shared library, Reason: image not found

Tags: python, macos, shared-libraries, dylib, houdini

I'm trying to use the Houdini Python module that ships with the application and is part of Houdini's installation folder, outside the standard Python paths. After following the installation instructions, running the *Houdini Terminal 16.5.571* script and adding `/Applications/Houdini/Houdini16.5.571/Frameworks/Houdini.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/houdini/python2.7libs` to `_virtualenv_path_extensions.pth` in my `site-packages` folder the `hou` module can be imported, the Python part that is. However it fails loading the dynamic libraries.

### Error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "myscript.py", line 7, in <module>
    import hou
  File "/Applications/Houdini/Houdini16.5.571/Frameworks/Houdini.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/houdini/python2.7libs/hou.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _hou
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/Houdini/Houdini16.5.571/Frameworks/Houdini.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/houdini/python2.7libs/_hou.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/Houdini.framework/Versions/16.5.571/Houdini
  Referenced from: /Applications/Houdini/Houdini16.5.571/Frameworks/Houdini.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/houdini/python2.7libs/_hou.so
  Reason: image not found
```

All files and folders mentioned in the error message are located within the Houdini path `/Applications/Houdini/Houdini16.5.571/Frameworks/Houdini.framework/Versions/Current` with `Current` being a symlink to `16.5.571`.

**Python module**

```
Resources/houdini/python2.7libs/hou.py
```

The Python module is found.

**Shared libraries**

```
Resources/houdini/python2.7libs/_hou.so`
```

This contains a a reference to `@rpath/Houdini.framework/Versions/16.5.571/Houdini` which it is presumably trying to look up.

```
Houdini
```

This seems to link to the actual `dylib` files, containing `@loader_path/Libraries` and `dylib...@rpath/libHoudiniUI` etc. and many others.

I read here [Cannot find dynamic library when running a Python script from Bazel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40105625/cannot-find-dynamic-library-when-running-a-python-script-from-bazel) that SIP may be causing it but even after `ln -s` the shared libraries into `/usr/local/lib` the error still occured.

I am using `pyenv` but tried with the system Python environment, resulting in the same behaviour.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in [dyld: Library not loaded ... Reason: Image not loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703510/dyld-library-not-loaded-reason-image-not-loaded/17704255#17704255) pointed me into the right direction, suggesting to rewrite the dynamic library paths using `otool`.

Listing all libraries loaded by `_hou.so`, shows the following list, with `@rpath/Houdini.framework/Versions/16.5.571/Houdini` being the one that causes the issue.

```
otool -L /Applications/Houdini/Houdini16.5.571/Frameworks/Houdini.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/houdini/python2.7libs/_hou.so
/Applications/Houdini/Houdini16.5.571/Frameworks/Houdini.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/houdini/python2.7libs/_hou.so:
    @rpath/Houdini.framework/Versions/16.5.571/Houdini (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 16.5.255)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 300.0.0, current version 1443.14.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 275.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 22.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Versions/A/QTKit (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 492.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.0)
```

Rewriting the path can be done using `install_name_tool -change`.

```
install_name_tool -change @rpath/Houdini.framework/Versions/16.5.571/Houdini /Applications/Houdini/Houdini16.5.571/Frameworks/Houdini.framework/Versions/16.5.571/Houdini /Applications/Houdini/Houdini16.5.571/Frameworks/Houdini.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/houdini/python2.7libs/_hou.so
```

It may be better to use a relative path.