# Issues with installing TensorFlow on a Mac OS (10.12.1)

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, tensorflow

I've spent more than 3 hours with installing a GPU enabled TensorFlow, although, it is still not working.

I went with the "pip" install guide.

Here are the tasks I've done, in order:

**1.1 download and install the CUDA Toolkit (.dmg v8.0)**

**1.2 download and unzip CUDA Deep Neural Network (cuDNN v5)**

**1.3 copy files**

```
cd ~/Downloads/cuda
sudo mv include/cudnn.h /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/include/
sudo mv lib/libcudnn* /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib
sudo ln -s /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib/
```

**2.1 set variables**

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CUDA_HOME/lib64:$CUDA_HOME/extras/CUPTI/lib64"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$CUDA_HOME/lib"
export PATH="$CUDA_HOME/bin:$PATH"

export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl
```

**3.1 install pip**

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

**3.2 install tensorflow**

```
sudo pip install tensorflow --ignore-installed numpy
```

**3.3 install binary**

```
sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Finally, when I want to check if TensorFlow is working, I enter Python and simply import it:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
```

Here's the complete error message I get:

```
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH $ORIGIN/../../_solib_darwin/_U@local_Uconfig_Ucuda_S_Scuda_Ccudart___Uexternal_Slocal_Uconfig_Ucuda_Scuda_Slib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so being ignored in restricted program because it is a relative path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH ../local_config_cuda/cuda/lib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so being ignored in restricted program because it is a relative path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH ../local_config_cuda/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so being ignored in restricted program because it is a relative path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer here.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/41073045/1831325

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a simple

```
sudo pip uninstall tensorflow
sudo pip install tensorflow --ignore-installed numpy
```

did the trick...