# How to fix tensorflow tutorial (mnist for beginner) error?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, mnist

I am trying to tensorflow mnist tutorial for beginner in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist.py).

When I executed tutorial script, it causes the following error.
How to fix this error?

it seems like failing to get mnist image data.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mnist2.py", line 35, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found


Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is an issue with the images. I think the relevant line is:

```
Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
```

You are not loading the necessary CUDA libraries.
Is it your intention to install with CUDA/GPU support? If so you should take a look at the relevant section on the 
 [tensorflow installation page](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/get_started/os_setup.html#optional-linux-enable-gpu-support).

Answer (score 0):

You are not finding CUDA on your system.

Please take a look at my answer here.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41073045/1831325