# tensorflow ImportError "@rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib" Image Not Found

Tags: python, macos, installation, tensorflow

Trying Tensorflow in Mac Sierra with cuda_gpu, python 2.7 from system default, no virtual environment.

Encounter ImportError when doing basic test "import tensorflow"

```
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH $ORIGIN/../../_solib_darwin/_U@local_Uconfig_Ucuda_S_Scuda_Ccudart___Uexternal_Slocal_Uconfig_Ucuda_Scuda_Slib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so being ignored in restricted program because it is a relative path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH ../local_config_cuda/cuda/lib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so being ignored in restricted program because it is a relative path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH ../local_config_cuda/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so being ignored in restricted program because it is a relative path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I've tried the steps of "local_config_cuda" suggested by @norman_h from ['Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.7.5.dylib' TensorFlow Error on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710339/library-not-loaded-rpath-libcudart-7-5-dylib-tensorflow-error-on-mac), but still not working.

CUDA samples work, so it looks an issue of lib reference... can one shed me 
some light? thanks!

Comment: need to disable SIP (security integrity protection) and set dyld/ld library paths and also path variable to include location of cuda libraries

Comment: after disabling SIP, the whole thing immediately works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Per above comment from @Yaroslav, disabling SIP resolves the issue immediately.