# from _future_ import print_function

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I recently intsalled Tensorflow 1.13.1 in my mac. I use python 3.6.8.
I tried running the following lines in anaconda jupyter notebook

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
```

which returns the following error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     40     sys.setdlopenflags(_default_dlopen_flags | ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
---> 41   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     42   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
    344 

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/solomon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcublas.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/solomon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
  Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-7f78a08bd780> in <module>
      1 from __future__ import print_function
----> 2 import tensorflow as tf
      3 import numpy as np

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *
     25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     26 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>
     49 import numpy as np
     50 
---> 51 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     52 
     53 # Protocol buffers

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     50 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     51 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 52   raise ImportError(msg)
     53 
     54 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/solomon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/Users/solomon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/Users/solomon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Users/solomon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Users/solomon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/solomon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcublas.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/solomon/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I have been stuck in this for quite sometime. It took me a lot of effort to even post this in stack overflow.
Any kind of useful suggestions and help would be strongly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.7.5.dylib' TensorFlow Error on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710339/library-not-loaded-rpath-libcudart-7-5-dylib-tensorflow-error-on-mac)

Comment: Thanks. I wish you posted earlier. I had to resolve it myself !
Thanks anyway !