# Run Tensorflow with GPU in Pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, gpu

I want to run Tensorflow GPU in Pycharm on Windows 10, Cuda v11.1 and cuDNN v8.0.4.

I tried some guides like these

https://medium.com/@ashkan.abbasi/quick-guide-for-installing-python-tensorflow-and-pycharm-on-windows-ed99ddd9598

[How to run Tensorflow GPU in Pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549257/how-to-run-tensorflow-gpu-in-pycharm)

I installed   https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads and https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download.

I downloaded cudnn and unzipped it directly in the Cuda installation folder, is that correct? At `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\`

[image]

---

At the point **4- Install cuDNN Library** on the medium blog I couldn't find the folder `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVSMI`.

Do I have to install something extra to keep the folder, or was it renamed?

---

At the point **5- Install Tensorflow** on the medium blog Tensorflow GPU is installed. I installed it with `pip install tensorflow-gpu`, but I don't have Anaconda Prompt.

Is there an option to run the gpu without installing Anaconda Prompt? How could I bypass the step?

Answer (score 0):

You can install it in any Terminal without Anaconda prompt also using below line.

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

You can follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) documentation about compatibility and Environment Variable setup.

You can also follow [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-and-gpu-support-on-windows-10-60693e46e781) post for installation using V`isual Studio Express`.